# tkinter label does not respond to button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a small GUI which will open other python codes, but I want the GUI to display a label saying what is happening. My code for now is as follows.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import sys

master = Tk()

def tryout():
    sign.config(master, text = "Hmm") 

sign = Label(master, text = "Sup").grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
butTest = Button(master, text='test', command=tryout)
butTest.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

mainloop( )
```

I want the label that says 'Sup' to change to 'Hmm' when I press button `butTest` but instead an error pops up.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/import.py", line 8, in tryout
    sign.config(master, text = "Hmm")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

What changes will I have to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the label and it's grid separately

```
Sign = Label()
Sign.grid()
```

See the type of

```
Label(). grid ()
```

It is None because grid method returns none and you assign it to sign.
So,

```
 sign = none
```

And none has no attribute called config. That's why the error occurs

Also remove `master,` from the `def tryout():` section or else there will be a '_tkinter.TclError: unknown option' error.

Thanks, C Vith, for debugging the code (Also remove ..... error) Suggested by C Vith